# Run SSIS package based on a flag in database table

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package which I need to schedule based on flags from a table.

I have an export flag in one of SQL Server 2012 tables. As soon as this flag is set to 1, I need to run the SSIS package.

Note : The server with the SSIS package and the server with the SQL Server 2012 table are different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably starting SSIS by executing sp_start_job is not a good solution because job might be already running. Service broker sounds like a better approach. So, I am deleting my answer as not a perfect one.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at an Event based activity. That smells like a trigger. However, since you're needing to go across servers, you're probably looking at something like service broker or some other messaging queue.

You will then build out the stored procedure call to start the SSIS package on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for the response @billinkc. I looked up [sp_start_job](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9412dfbc-4183-40be-902f-379b58c61670/spstartjob-can-i-use-this-to-run-a-job-on-another-server) but that is not working.